# Python -> BEELINE ParseException line 1:1 cannot recognize input near '!' 'sh' 'echo'

Tags: python, hive

I am writing a Python script that parses the metadata using beeline CLI and spews out a file for me to parse. I am having trouble to pass the right escape character sequence from Python -> Beeline script.

Here are my code snippets

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import commands
import subprocess
import sys
hive_cmd =  "beeline -u \"jdbc:hive2://$(hostname -f):10000/;principal=hive/_HOST@some_company.COM\"  \
             --silent=true\
             --outputformat=csv2\
             --showHeader=false\
             --force=true\
             --showWarnings=false\
              -e 'USE some_database; "

if __name__ == '__main__':
    describe_table_cmd = ""
    f = open('run_dml.sql', 'w+')
    tables_list_cmd = hive_cmd + "SHOW TABLES;'"
    status, tables_list = commands.getstatusoutput(tables_list_cmd)
    for table_name in tables_list.splitlines():
        if not 'HotSpot' in table_name:
            describe_table_cmd += "\!sh echo {0};\ndescribe {0};\n".format(str(table_name))
        if table_name == "2table":
            break
    print(describe_table_cmd)
    status2, columns_list = commands.getstatusoutput(hive_cmd + describe_table_cmd + "'")
    for line in columns_list.splitlines():
        f.write("{0}\n".format(line))
    f.close()
```

This is the console output:

```
[username@server ~]$ ./r.py
\!sh echo 1table;
describe 1table;
\!sh echo 2table;
describe 2table;

[username@server ~]$
```

And this is what is in the run_dml.sql

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:1 cannot recognize input near '!' 'sh' 'echo' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Obviously, I am trying to run the echo statement on the shell to get the table output. If there is a better way to get the hive metadata(both table_names and their columns) dynamically, I am all ears. Until then, this is the offending code.

```
describe_table_cmd += "\!sh echo {0};\ndescribe {0};\n".format(str(table_name))
```

Comment: I've never been able to get beeline to run shell commands like the hive cli could.  I'd suggest using a shell script to execute your beeline command.  You can redirect that to an array and parse it in your shell script, or to a file and parse it however you like.

Comment: @Andrew Even if I write this in shell, how would the echo command work differently? The command still has to be run on the beeline no? I want this to come out of Hive/Python/Shell **Table1 : Columna Columnb; Table2 : Columnc** Etc.... Ideally if I can get this into a Python dictionary with key value pairing. Would prefer to write in Python, since I am learning Python, but shell is acceptable also. I want to do it on the fly. Not sure if you noticed, the output of the first beeline command is setting up the input for the second.

Comment: Alright, I have been able to use the HERE document in the shell script to build my beeline command and pass to it. This might help somebody in the future.